# Rails validating search params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have an API which is fairly restful but am struggling to work out how to implement a search cleanly. I want to be able to search for all the records between two date-times, the date-times are allowed to be a maximum of 6 hours apart. At the moment in my controller method I have the following:

```
required_params = [:start_time, :end_time]
if check_required_params(required_params, params) and check_max_time_bound(params, 6.hours)
   ... rest of controller code here ...
end
```

check_required_params is an application method that looks like this:

```
def check_required_params(required_params, params_sent)
required_params.each do |param|
  unless has_param(param, params_sent)
    unprocessable_entity
    return false
  end
end
  true
end
```

check_max_time is fairly similar.

I know it's against best practices to do validation in the controller but I can't see how I can add it to the model cleanly.

Comment: I like the question, but I don't understand what prevents you from moving all that code (except the `unprocessable_entity`) to the model. Note also that `check_required_params` can be simplified a lot using array intersections, no need to loop.

Comment: @tokland Ok, I could do that. I guess I was hoping I could use the built in Active::Model validations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually what you are doing is (almost) `best practice` and will (almost) be incorporated in Rails 4 with `strong parametsers`.  (I say almost because your `check_max_time` looks like it should be a validation in your model.)

You should go ahead and pull in the feature today and make upgrades easier on yourself.  Strong Parameters  https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Documentation is there, but here is how you incorporate it.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  def create
    # Doesn't have to be an ActiveRecord model
    @results = Search.create(search_params)
    respond_with @results
  end

  private

  def search_params
    # This will ensure that you have :start_time and :end_time, but will allow :foo and :bar
    params.require(:start_time, :end_time).permit(:foo, :bar #, whatever else)
  end
end

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :time_less_than_six_hours

  private

  def time_less_than_six_hours
    errors.add(:end_time, "should be less than 6 hours from start") if (end_time - start_time) > 6.hours
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like your `registration_id` is a string and not a hash. Rewrite it like this: `params[:user].require(:registration_id); params[:user].permit(:device_name, :os_type)`. The way Strong Parameters works has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Never found a clean answer for this. However if you're making an API [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) has inbuilt Parameter Validation and Coercion to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would do in this scenario is the set the default value between these two datetimes so that i won't have to do validation and raise the exception.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :assign_default_params

  def index
  end

  private
  def assign_default_params
    params[:start_time] ||= Time.now
    params[:end_time]   ||= params[:start_time] + 6.hours
    params[:end_time]     = params[:start_time] + 6.hours if ((params[:end_time] - params[:start_time]) / 3600).round) > 6
  end
end
```

With this code above, it always has the params required to the search. The method `assign_default_params` try to assign default values if they are not sent from the clients. The last thing it does is that it assign `params[:end_time]` to a maximum value.

It's much neater because we don't have to do validation and the client won't need to handle different response code such as `422`. And you should have an API documentation, stating about this fact as well.

Comment: What about validating the dates can only be a maximum of 6 hours apart?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'd rather return the 422...otherwise it could return unexpected results for people using the API.

Comment: An API should have documentation, that is the way for people who consume the api should know and how it behaves like twitter api and facebook graph api.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I would rather error if the consumer of the API tries to do something silly instead of silently change their input.

Comment: An API that changes what is asked for isn't really a good result. Imagine if you ask for all the tweets for a week but it actually returns them for the last hour. That is not expected at all